# Solaris/Unix: How to display only new lines from log file since last check

Tags: bash, unix, sunos

The machine is SunOS 5.10 so it behaves a bit differently than Unix.
I have an error log file that is filled by multiple users.
I get my entries by:

`tail error.log | grep USER1`

I get results in the format:

```
Jan 16 09:06:18 XYZ USER1
Jan 16 09:22:12 XYZ USER1
Jan 16 11:22:30 XYZ USER1
```

What I need is a command that would only print my errors that were logged after the last time I checked and print nothing otherwise.
I decided to get my last entry into another file by:

`grep USER1 error.log | tail -1 > temp_error.log`

From there I'd cut only the first chars containing the date by:

`less temp_error.log | cut -c 1-15`

This would give me the result:

`Jan 16 11:22:30`

I then use a 'sed' command to get all lines after this one in the file:

`sed -e '1,/Jan 16 11:22:30/d' error.log | grep USER1`

This would work but of course I have to paste the date every time. I decided to automate this with a variable by executing the below commands:

```
LAST_ENTRY=`less temp_error.log | cut -c 1-15` 
sed -e '1,/$LAST_ENTRY/d' error.log | grep USER1
```

This doesn't work because the variable is not passed correctly to the 2nd command and I don't understand why. Please, help me to understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: change single quotes to double quotes :  `sed -e "1,/$LAST_ENTRY/d"`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul You beat me by a second. you need double quotes for variable expansion in bash.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: Thank you, it works!

Comment: I have one additional question. My sed command would list all entries after the first occurrence of the string, and if there were multiple entries with the same timestamp, it would list them all. Is there a way in the sed pattern to specify that I want the last occurrence of the string and not the first?